# How to change column order in Grafana InfluxDb Table

Tags: grafana

I have table like this:
[image]
And I need to have "last" column (it is `value` from influxDb) in first column.
It is InfluxDb version `1.7`.

I have a lot of queries (A,B,C,D):
[image]

So I can't use `organize fields` transformation:
[image]
But if I do `join` transformation before (regardless of the field) my table looks like this:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Grafana `Organize fields` transformation and drag/drop fields to achieve desired order. Example:

[image]

If query consist of a lot of series (A,B,C,D), probably it is necessary to do `Merge` transformation before `Organize fields`:
[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, I have a lot of queries (A,B,C,D) and this type of transform is not possible when I have more than 1 query :/

Comment: @sosnus why it is not possible? There is another type of transformation to merge multiple results into one result and then organize can be applied